# Tengo un problema con ORACLE, System.Data.OracleClient

Tags: c#, oracle

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado

Oracle IDE: 4.0.3.16.84 y
Visual Studio 2015

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
        OracleCommand oracommand = new OracleCommand();
        OracleDataReader lector;
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = XXXX; User Id = XXXX; Password = XXXX; Unicode = true;";
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            oracommand.Parameters.Add("consec", Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            oracommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            LNumDoc.Text = (string)(oracommand.Parameters["consec"].Value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "XXXX.");
        }
        con.Close();
```

Al ejecutarlo me sale este error: **System.Data.OracleClient requiere la version 8.1.7 o posterior del software cliente Oracle**

Comment: Que version de oracle estas usando ?. Que version de .net estas usando?

Comment: Lo actualice en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En un principio te recomiendo que quites las referencias de

> System.Data.OracleClient;

y luego instales el conector de oracle

> Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess -Version 12.2.1100

Luego que cambies el Connection String de esta forma

```
        const string _protocol = "TCP";
        const string _schema = "xx";
        const string _pswSchema = "xx";
        const string _host = "xx";
        const string _port = "1521";
        const string _serviceName = "xx";

        const string _cnnString = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=" + _protocol + ")(HOST=" + _host + ")"
                             + "(PORT=" + _port + ")))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=" + _serviceName + ")))";
```

Luego en tu código

```
    using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

    //
    var oracleConnectionStringBuilder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = _cnnString,
                UserID = _schema ,
                Password = _pswSchema 
            };

    string cnnStringFormat2 = "Data Source=" + _cnnString + ";User Id="+ _schema + ";Password="+ _pswSchema ;
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oracleConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());
    OracleCommand oracommand = new OracleCommand("get_secuencia",con);
    oracommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    OracleDataReader lector;

    try
    {
       con.Open();
       oracommand.Parameters.Add("consec", Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
       oracommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       LNumDoc.Text = oracommand.Parameters["consec"].Value.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "XXXX.");
    }
    con.Close();
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81848/discussion-on-answer-by-luciano-montanez-tengo-un-problema-con-oracle-system-da).